# "Self Programming" vs "In Application Programming"

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, avr

I was referring to Atmega controllers and LPC2148 microcontrollers. Atmel talks of "Self Programming" whereas NXP talks of "In Application Programming". Are both of these technologies conceptually same? Meaning we can program even remotely without connecting a programmer or PC with appropriate SW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are referring to has to do with programming the flash in the part, the flash that contains the firmware the part runs on.   There are two big picture categories for programming that part.  One is with the processor in the part stopped you program that part from some software outside the part, a host, a device programmer, whatever through pins on the part.  The second big category is the software on the part programs the memory on the part all within the part.  Not self modifying code, but say there are N banks of program flash, one bank of flash can be running a program (say a bootloader) that has the ability to program other banks.  bootloader one, another use case is the part has the ability via ethernet for example to go and check for firmware updates.

For the outside in case there are interfaces designed/defined by the chip vendor for stopping the processor (ideally) and programming the flashes.  For the inside to inside case there are interfaces that are part of the inside processors address space to perform the same task albeit not necessarily exactly the same way.  So the documentation needs to separate the two major approaches because both have addresses and timing diagrams, etc that are required to explain how to do it.

Each vendor be it engineering or marketing or legal department or a combination may come up with different terms for the same thing for various reasons mostly to avoid you confusing our part with their part.  NXP wouldnt want you googling in application programming and find some atmel part and then switch to atmel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They both mean the programs you write can update the chip's program memory (flash). This functionality can be used to implement a boot loader etc.

In the early days you had to physically un-socket the program memory chip and use a special programmer tool to load the code. Then we had In System Programming - which meant you could hook up a special tool to a few pins on the chip and program it without having to remove it from the board. After that came In Application Programming - which meant the chip could program itself.

You can see how this can be a bit confusing so I think that is why Atmel just uses the more descriptive term 'self programming' for IAP.